# Error when building iPhone project with blowfish C library imported for password encryption

Tags: iphone, c, blowfish

I downloaded blowfish reference source code [here](http://www.schneier.com/blowfish-download.html) then when I try to use it, I well imported "blowfish.h" and setup target references for "blowfish.lib".

When I declare my key like :

```
BF_KEY *key;
```

it works well but as soon I call a method defind in "blowfish.h" like :

```
const char *keyStr = [HP_APP_KEY UTF8String];

BF_set_key(key, strlen(keyStr),(unsigned char*)keyStr);
```

I got this error when trying to build project:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "_BF_set_key", referenced from:
>         -[HPNetworkController authenticateUser:withPassword:] in HPNetworkController.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

any help is welcoming, thanks guys ;)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, the "Reference Source Code" does not contain a library for iOS. `.lib` is an extension commonly used for win32 libraries. Indeed, if you try:

```
 lipo -info blowfish.lib
```

you will get an error message.

So, I think you should compile blowfish yourself for iOS and link it to your project.